# Android: resume a singleTask activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launchmode

I have an activity with an UDP socket on a port. If I press the Home button the activity goes in background, *OnPause()* and *OnStop()* methods are called. Now I want to resume my activity when I receive some UDP packet. 
Reading the other posts I understand I have to:

1. declare the activity as `android:launchMode="singleTask"` (or `singleInstance`)
2. Then, when I want to resume the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), myActivity.class);

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(intent);
```

This solution does not work form me. The call to `startActivity(intent)` does not show my activity on foreground and `onResume()` is not called.

The following flags do the job but I don't want to clear the task and restart a new one.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Comment: your udp socket is in a service, right?

Comment: The socket is in the service when the main activity is closed. When I create the main activity the socket is unbound in the service and the main activity binds it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to bring your own task to the foreground, you need to call `startActivity()` on a non-Activity Context, for example:

```
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Also, you don't need to use any special launch mode (`singleTask` or `singleInstance`) for this to work.

This is an Android bug that was fixed in Android 4.4. Since this question is from 2014, I will assume that OP was seeing this problem.

See [How to resume Android Activity programmatically from background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766270/how-to-resume-android-activity-programmatically-from-background/29769255#29769255) and the comment thread.